# AngularJS: how to concatenate string with $scope value in a controller

Tags: angularjs

what i wanted to do sounds pretty simple but, the result i got is awkward for me.
there is a view with a text filed:

```
<input colorpicker="hex" type="text" ng-model="item.bgcolor" style="background:{{item.bgcolor}}"/>
```

In the controller i want to bind the value of the text field and concatenate with string variable like this :

```
var page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';
```

the result is `hello undefined world`
but if i did `console.log($scope.item.bgcolor);` i get the text field value in the console.
the controller code:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.item = {
    bgcolor: $scope.bgcolor,
  };

  var page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';
  $scope.show = function() {
    console.log('page', page);
    console.log('bgcolor', $scope.item.bgcolor);
  };
})
```

the main view code:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label>Background color</label>
        <input colorpicker="hex" type="text" ng-model="item.bgcolor" style="background:{{item.bgcolor}}"/>
        <label>Header color</label>
        <input colorpicker="hex" type="text" ng-model="item.headercolor" style="background:{{item.headercolor}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
 .state('app.main', {
      url: '/main',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'mainCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: put your controller code

Comment: Where are you referencing mainCtrl from HTML? Where is $scope.bgcolor being set (which mainCtrl uses to initialize $scope.item.bgcolor)?

Comment: i can't see why this important, but i added the code anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this .. you don't need to do extra efforts just use `watch` method and change page value on the change of object ..

**watch collection will fire at every change of your item object**

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return $scope.item ;},function(n,o){
    page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';
});
```

**your controller**

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.item = {
    bgcolor: null,
  };

   var page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';

  $scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return $scope.item ;},function(n,o){
       page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';
   });

  var page = 'hello' + $scope.item.bgcolor + 'world';
  $scope.show = function() {
    console.log('page', page);
    console.log('bgcolor', $scope.item.bgcolor);
  };
})
```

[Here is the working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OvHMAIpI60poUqew66qy?p=info)

Comment: i tried to avoid $watch but i think its the solution for this. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `ng-style` instead of style like this:

```
ng-style="background-color: item.bgcolor"
```

Also, post your your complete view and controller code. If your colorpicker input is in an `ng-repeat` you ca't use it like `$scope.item.bgcolor` in your controller.

**EDIT:**

There's no `$scope.bgcolor` in your controller. you have to define it first like this:

```
$scope.bgcolor = 'green'
```

followed by your `item` object:

```
$scope.item = {
    bgcolor: $scope.bgcolor
}
```

Comment: colorpicket is a dirctive [link](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker) my controller and view code is abit big i'll post the part of this issue only and i don't think there is a need for the other parts of code.

Comment: well the main problem is you are not setting $scope.bgcolor